# Inteli Idea: Change parent color scheme

Tags: intellij-idea, appearance

When I apply this colour scheme, then all the colours of my interface change to `Darcula`. What should I change that it use the `Default` or `Intellij Idea Light` scheme?
[Source Code](https://github.com/akulik512/intellij-settings-repository/blob/master/one_dark_vivid_italic.icls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<property name="originalScheme">One Dark Vivid Italic</property>
```

with

```
<property name="originalScheme">_@user_Default</property>
```

in the .icls.

If it does not help, then please describe how exactly you apply this scheme to the IDE.

Comment: Hello Ekaterina! I don't have this line `<property name="originalScheme">One Dark Vivid Italic</property>` in my file.
I apply this scheme as follows: `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Color Scheme` -> chose `Scheme`

Comment: I tried use `<scheme name="_@user_Default" version="142" parent_scheme="Default">` but didn't work.

Comment: AFAICS, that line is there in the file you pointed to on the GitHub, it's the last line before the </metaInfo> tag. Anyway if that does not help it would be great if you describe how this scheme was obtained, what result you expect after importing it and what happens instead. That is ,what IDE theme is there in Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance before you import this Editor scheme, what appears after import and whether there is any notification like "You are trying to set dark Editor scheme, would you like to apply dark theme to the entire IDE".

Comment: Hello @Ekaterina Valeeva. Thanks for your answer but I decided to go through another way and change all settings manually. Anyway, we can mark this comment as an answer!